# php-How to get selected items from one page and display ALL those specific items on another page?

Tags: php, jquery

I have two pages. The `menu.php`is where all the items from database is displayed and has an "ADD" button to add these items. The items are supposed to be added to a table in another page(addtocart.php). The problem is it only adds the first item that i click the "Add" button for. And when i do the same for other items, it does nothing.

[Here is a picture of menu.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hb1tw.jpg)

Here only one item is being added and when i go back and click on add button again for another item, nothing happens in the table. It keeps that one item only, no updation.
[Addtocart.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9UYm.png)

Here is the code for `menu.php`

```
       <div id = "breakfast2">
        <h2>Breakfast</h2>
        <?php
        $conn1 = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cart_mexican") or    

      die();
        $dbsql1 = "SELECT * FROM breakfast ORDER BY id ";

        $query1 = mysqli_query($conn1, $dbsql1);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($query1) > 0)  
            {  
        while($row1= mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1) or die)
            { 
            ?>
            <div class = "col-md-4">
    <form method = "POST" action ="addtocart.php?action = add &id=<?phpecho   
    $row1 ['id']; ?>">

    <img src = "<?php echo $row1["image_path"]; ?>" class = "img-responsive"   
  /><br>
    <h4 class ="text-primary"><?php echo $row1["name"]; ?></h4>
    <center><h4 class = "text-primary">Rs <?php echo $row1["price"]; ?></h4>  
   </center>
    <input type = "text" name ="quantity" class = "form-control" 
   style="width: 260px" />
    <input type = "hidden" name ="hidden_name" value = "<?php echo 
   $row1["name"]; ?>" />
    <input type = "hidden" name ="hidden_price" value = "<?php echo 
   $row1["price"]; ?>" />
    <center><input type = "submit" name ="add_to_cart" style = "margin-
 left:0px; margin-top: 5px;" class ="btn btn-small btn-success" value=   
 "Add"/>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>

        <?php
    }
            }
        ?>
```

Here is the code for `addtocart.php`

```
    <?php   
        session_start();  
        $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "cart_mexican");  
        if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))  
        {  
        if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))  
            {  
       $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION["shopping_cart"], "item_id");  
       if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))  
       {  
            $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);  
            $item_array = array(  
                 'item_id'               =>     $_GET["id"],  
                 'item_name'               =>     $_POST["hidden_name"],  
                 'item_price'          =>     $_POST["hidden_price"],  
                 'item_quantity'          =>     $_POST["quantity"]  
            );  
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            echo '<script>alert("Item Already Added")</script>';  
            echo '<script>window.location="addtocart.php"</script>';  
       }  
        }  
        else  
            {  
       $item_array = array(  
            'item_id'               =>     $_GET["id"],  
            'item_name'               =>     $_POST["hidden_name"],  
            'item_price'          =>     $_POST["hidden_price"],  
            'item_quantity'          =>     $_POST["quantity"]  
       );  
       $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;  
        }  
        }  
        if(isset($_GET["action"]))  
        {  
        if($_GET["action"] == "delete")  
        {  
            foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  
        {  
            if($values["item_id"] == $_GET["id"])  
            {  
                 unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);  
                 echo '<script>alert("Item Removed")</script>';  
                 echo '<script>window.location="addtocart.php"</script>';  
            }  
        }  
        }  
        }  
        ?>
```

html code for the table

```
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  

            <div style="clear:both"></div>  
            <br />  
            <h3>Order Details</h3>  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <table class="table table-bordered">  
                      <tr>  
                           <th width="40%">Item Name</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Quantity</th>  
                           <th width="20%">Price</th>  
                           <th width="15%">Total</th>  
                           <th width="5%">Action</th>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php   
                      if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))  
                      {  
                           $total = 0;  
                 foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  
                           {  
                      ?>  
                      <tr>  
                           <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?></td>  
                           <td>Rs <?php echo $values["item_price"]; ?></td>  
                           <td>Rs <?php echo 
   number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"], 2); ?>   
  </td>  
                           <td><a href="addtocart.php?action=delete&id=<?php 
    echo $values["item_id"]; ?>"><span class="text-danger">Remove</span></a>   
   </td>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php  
     $total =  $total +  ($values["item_quantity"]*$values["item_price"]);  
                           }  
                      ?>  
                      <tr>  
                           <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>  
                           <td align="right">Rs <?php echo   

     number_format($total, 2); ?></td>  
                           <td></td>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php  
                      }  
                      ?>  
                 </table>  
            </div>  
       </div>
```

Comment: I think the new data overrides the old one.

Comment: New data isnt overriding the old one. Because it only adds the first item, it does not add any new item afterwards. Means initially, if i click on any one item, it adds that item. And then i add another item from the menu page. It doesnt add this 2nd time.